# Python Names and Variables

Tags: python, pointers, variables, namespaces

I know this was addressed probably a thousand times already and might be a really dumb question. 
But what happens exactly if you create a python variabel(name)? 
For example if you type :
x = 2 
I know Python creates an intobject which holdsthe interger 2. But the x actually is a pointer to that object ? And in case it is, where is this pointer itself stored and does it consume memory? 
Sorry again for this horribly typed question (sucks doing it on the phone) and the question itself. 
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a name. The value associated with that name is an `int` object representing 2. Anything else is an implementation detail, not specified by the language itself.

Comment: `not specified by the language itself` - what does this mean? It has to be specified by the language. It is just not an important piece of information for the developer

Comment: @MikhailGenkin No, it doesn't. Take the order of keys in a `dict` as a recent well known example. In Python 3.6, the CPython implementation guaranteed that a `dict` would remember the insertion order of its keys and use that order for all iteration, but other implementations were free to use a different order, or disregard order at all. In Python 3.7, though, the *language* requires insertion order to be retained; if an implementation does not, that is a bug in the implementation.

Comment: I could write a valid Python implementation in which all values are stored in a SQL database, rather than in memory, and every lookup gets translated in to a SELECT query. Performance would be abysmal, but the semantics would be the same.